# Crystal Reports 2016 and ODBC, columns missing

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc

I know Crystal Reports 2016 is old, but please help. This issue only started recently, was working before. I'm not sure what changed.

[image]

Why are the columns and database name missing?

[image]

Logs show that ODBC is sending the command
1663950471:SHOW DATABASES LIKE ';
When it should be sending
1663950471:SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%';

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question.  I installed a newer version of ODBC, from 5.3.1 to 5.3.2.  Its weird how this all of a sudden started.  But I'm glad something fixed it.